# Add an (SVG-) image to an existing graph in R

Tags: image, r, import, svg, insets

I'd like to an an image (ideally an SVG) as an inset to an existing graph in R and put a black border around the image.

Is that possible with base-functions in R? Do I need packages for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the `grImport` package is what you are looking for ? It only seems to allow to import Posctscript files, however.

You can find two vignettes files [on the package web page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/index.html), which should help you learn how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your SVG to PostScript, then you can do all this good stuff:

http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Talks/import.pdf

If there's an easier way to convert from SVG to the RGML format mentioned there, that would be a better option.